# Why is there a '+' before and after the str()

Tags: python, json, string, concatenation

Why is there a '+' before and after the "str()" & "where"

**output = "["+str(lat)+","+str(lng)+", '"+where+"']"**

I know this is a bit of a silly question, but please help!

Cheersx

Comment: You are basically forming a string by the character [ "plus" whatever lat variable has, turned into a string "plus" a comma character plus whatever lng character has etc. It just combines characters and strings to form a final string.

Comment: How else should the compiler know to concatentate them?

Comment: Well, why is there a `+` before and after `4` in `3 + 4 + 5`?

Comment: By the way, it might be cleaner to write `output = "[%f,%f,'%s']" % (lat, lon, where)` assuming `lat` and `lon` are floating point and `where` is a string.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: str() is built-in function which convert argument to string-type and return value. And "+" is operator for concatenation some strings to one. See about common string operations in official docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 1):

Python only concatenates automatically between string literals. String expressions (like `str(something)`) need to be explicitly concatenated, which python does using the + operator

Comment: Thank you 3Doubloons :)
Cheersx

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are confused because at first glance, it looks like the line of code is building a list of three items, which is syntactically denoted by separating the items with commas and surrounding with square brackets. That like of code would look like

```
output = [str(lat), str(lng), where]
```

What you actually have is a line of code which builds a string (via concatenation) containing of:

- an open brace, `"["`
- the latitude, as a string `str(lat)`
- a comma, `","`
- the longitude, as a string `str(lng)`
- a comma and apostrophe, `",'"`
- the location, which is presumably already a string, `where`
- another apostrophe and close brace `"']"`

All of those are strings, and `+` operator concatenates them together.

Comment: Thank you SchighSchagh :) Although I'm aware of how concatenation works, I got a bit thrown off by the '+' before str(lat) & after where..